# Angular Material Input: Bug with many input fields

Tags: html, angular, angular-material

I have a problem with the Forms Module of Angular Material!
I try to create a  tag with many Angular Material Basic Inputs.
But on the website, only one Input field appears. The other input fields only show the value of the field. Now, when i click on the first input field, then the other fields appear correctly, but only when i click on the first input field?

[Before i clicked on the first input field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aznNm.png)

[And after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uybjb.png)

```
<form class="example-form" style="margin-top: 15px">
  <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
    <mat-label>Favorite food</mat-label>
    <input matInput placeholder="Ex. Pizza" value="Sushi" disabled>
  </mat-form-field>

  <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
    <mat-label>Favorite food</mat-label>
    <input matInput placeholder="Ex. Pizza" value="Sushi" disabled>
  </mat-form-field>
</form>
```

Comment: your screenshots are not of the inputs you describe. You have 2 disabled inputs which appears to be working correctly when inserted into a Stackblitz Example. Can you please create a minimal, reproduceable example there? https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-djhoeh

Comment: This is it! I only paste the example code from Angular Material, but in my project it doesnt work. Additionally my user informations, which come from a service, are also not shown in the header until i click on the first input field, althrough the header is a other component...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that in your case, there might be some render errors. I suspect this as you have a disabled button in the template, but on your screenshots they do not appear to be so.

Check you Browser console. (F12 o CTRL+SHIFT+i) If you refresh your app, can you see any errors? Those can make the app work in undeterministic ways. In the command line, where your run `ng serve` do you see any errors maybe? Fix these first, and try again.